# How can I move Windows 10 task bar program icons with the keyboard?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, icons

I want to change the positions of application icons that are pinned to the taskbar, but I want to do this with the keyboard.

For example, in a fresh Windows installation the default icons which are pinned to taskbar are *Windows store*, *File Explorer* and *Microsoft Edge*. If I e.g. want to move the Microsoft Edge icon to the last I can just click and drag the icon with the left mouse button.
But now I want to do this with the keyboard. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

No there isn't.

You can move application windows using keys, but not the icons on the Taskbar.

Answer (score 2):

Old post, but it's at the top of the Google results. On Windows 11 at least you can

move them with  <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd> arrows.

Use <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to get to the taskbar.

Comment: Did you verify this works for Windows 10? This solution doesn’t seem to do what the author wanted.

Comment: Thank You this, although this shortcut does not work on Windows 10 but I have Windows 11 PC as well on which it is working.